# Unable to compile with Android 'O' ASUS ASUS_Z010D (Android 6.0.1, API 23) (minSdk(API 25, O preview) != deviceSdk(API 23))

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I was just checking the new `SDK` of Android o preview, but I'm unable to compile with the downloaded `SDK`. it shows following error

```
ASUS ASUS_Z010D (Android 6.0.1, API 23) (minSdk(API 25, O preview) != deviceSdk(API 23))
```

My `Gradle` file code can be read as:

```
 compileSdkVersion 'android-O'
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0-rc1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "in.akash_deep.pre"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 'O'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, the Android O preview will work only on devices with Android O SDK running. That is a limitation of SDK previews.

Once the new SDK is released, you will be able to run it.